# Append dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I have two dictionaries coming from JSON files that look something like that:

```
dict1 = {"data": [{"text": "text1", "id": "id1"}, {"text": "text2", "id": "id2"}]}
dict2 = {"data": [{"text": "text3", "id": "id3"}, {"text": "text4", "id": "id4"}]}
```

I want to create the following out of them:

```
dict = {"data": [{"text": "text1", "id": "id1"}, {"text": "text2", "id": "id2"}, {"text": "text3", "id": "id3"}, {"text": "text4", "id": "id4"}]}
```

I tried different methods like:

```
dict = dict1.update(dict2)
```

or

```
dict = dict1.append(dict2)
```

Both wrong. I think the problems arise from the "data" part that I do need. Would be really grateful for help. Thanks.

Comment: The `dict` doesn't know the what the values are, so how could he understand that you want to extend the list? `update` simply replaces the value of a dictionary with the value found in the other dictionary, without performing any other operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dict={"data": dict1["data"] +dict2["data"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

`update` and `append` don't make any assumptions about your structure, so they can't work. You'll have to construct a new dictionary:

```
dict3 = {'data': [dict1['data'] + dict2['data']]}
```

Or modify one of the existing ones:

```
dict1['data'].extend(dict2['data'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately by doing this:

```
dict = dict1.update(dict2)
```

you actually *replace* the value for "`data`" key, so you receive different results (the values are not merged).

Try this:

```
from itertools import chain

your_dicts = [dict1, dict2]  # Whatever you need, eg. iterable with many dicts 
result = {"data": list(chain.from_iterable(d['data'] for d in your_dicts))}
```

This will work with many dictionaries, even iterator through them. It does not require you to explicitly list them during dictionary creation.

Proof: http://ideone.com/V1HHNR